# IMAP connection handling

Tags: php, connection, imap

I wanna to create a little webmail client with PHP. I get the mails via IMAP and use the PHP IMAP Class (http://php.net/manual/en/ref.imap.php).

Is it better to keep the imap connection after a request alive or to connect and close after a request?

Answer (score 1):

If your client is web-browser based, IMAP connection is closed automatically upon script execution is done. Even if you make your connection stay alive, I see no way one could persist "connection resource" between requests.

Of course you could try some unrecommended, ugly hacks like never-ending script or dive into HTML5 and it's websockets.

Answer (score 1):

PHP will close the connection anyway, so in terms of programming it's always nicer to clean up after yourself, and close it explicitly.